# UISplitViewController not working on Iphone (set programmatically)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

This is my first time work on UISplitViewController. I am wondering why the following codes not showing displayModeButtonItem when I simulate using Iphones but works fine for Ipads. It's said in WWDC 2014 that UISplitViewController works for Iphones too, so I thought they should work the same. Am I missing something here?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
MySplitViewController *c = [[MySplitViewController alloc] init];
TableViewController *dc = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
SlideViewTableViewController *sc=[[SlideViewTableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

UINavigationController *dn = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dc];
UINavigationController *sn = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sc];
c.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sn, dn, nil];
dc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = c.displayModeButtonItem;
c.delegate = self;
c.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
c.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 200.0 / 2;
c.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 200.0;
c.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction=.3;


[self.window setRootViewController:c];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: Which iPhone are you using? Only on a 6+ it will show master & detail simulatenously: http://whoisryannystrom.com/2014/11/17/UISplitViewController-iOS-7/

Comment: if you watched wwdc 2014, it probably means, that the functionality appeared since ios 8. So what is version of iOS on your iPhone. At the same time, I suppose there should be more code, than you have shown.

Comment: Thank you!! And sorry for the dumb questions, I thought it was the version of iOS has to be 6.0 or above...